# Can I lose a full branch with its history in git?

Tags: git

I am currently taking my first steps using git. Can you please tell me if the following scenario is possible?

Let's imagine a branch for an old version of a software that is needed only very rarely. Let's say, it points to commit 6c0508c3e. Now, some developer deletes the branch. First issue: changes to branches are not tracked. So I cannot detect who did it.

Question 1: Is this correct? Can I really not detect who deleted the branch?

But at least the commit is still there (only not reachable anymore). So the code can still be retrieved using the commit's hash (6c0508c3e). But after some time, the git garbage collection detects that the commit is unreachable and will actually delete the commit 6c0508c3e.

Then, a few years later, some other developer wants to patch the old version. But the branch is gone. And there is no way to retrieve the code, since the GC deleted it.

Question 2: Is this possible as well?

Comment: Is there a scenario in which that can happen? Of course: you just described it. Is it likely? Not really. If you have multiple people working on it, there will me multiple clones, and the odds of no one noticing before all of them independently deleting their copy of the branch, and getting GC'd are pretty low.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I just cannot really believe it. I have been working with different version control systems in the past: once code reached the repository, it was always safe: You could always restore the exact state of the branch at this point in time and see who changed it afterwards.
Git seems to fail here in multiple ways: Restoring this state in time is not possible by design. The code may even get lost forever. And you can not even see who did it.
As I said: I cannot really believe that a modern VCS has these issues.

Comment: You can configure git to not prune. Ever. The point is that it not only has these cleanup features that some people (not you maybe) want, but it gives you the flexibility to configure them however you like.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you, I could do that. This feels a lot like using the recycle bin to store files that I might still need in the future and configure the OS to never clear the bin. It's possible, of course, but probably unstable in the long run. Working against the concept of a software is not a good idea IMO in most cases.

Comment: Turning off GC is not at all working against Git. You have to decide if you want your commits to live forever or not if the answer is not, then you can't complain when they get cleaned up. There are other ways you can prevent developers from deleting branches or tags by the way.

Comment: You are inventing problems to be worried about. "Once code reached the repository, it was always safe" the same is true of Git. Git won't "lose" your code. But if you allow untrusted parties unilateral access to your repo, then yes, they can delete branch names. Don't allow untrusted people to delete things from your repo.

Comment: @user229044 The last sentence is the important one IMO: in all other version controls I worked with, a normal employee could "only" create a mess that takes some time to get sorted out. If he does that, he will get caught and fired. In git, he can actually delete stuff for good without git documenting his identity.

Comment: @MadPhysicist "Turning off GC is not at all working against Git." By default, git is designed and configured to lose specific changes made to the repository. And there is no flag to say "Don't do that". There is only a flag to disable that part of the garbage collection process. That's different in the semantics. With the latter, there is no guarantee that this the only change necessary to avoid deletion of commits. And even if it is, it is always possible that a future version might add another feature that deletes the commits anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the statements I got, the answer is "yes" to both questions.

Normally, source control systems give you two very basic promises:
"Once your code reaches the repository, it will always be possible to restore this exact state. And you will always be able to track who changed this state."

Git violates these promises:

- You cannot reliably restore a certain point in time.
- A state can even be lost forever.
- You cannot even reliably track down who did it.

And the accepted answer seems to be: "Just be careful what you do."

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Git is about *distributed* version control.

*You* control your repository.  I have my own repository; you *don't* control this one.  You literally can't.

If you don't want to delete names, so that you don't lose commit hash IDs, just don't delete the names and you won't lose the commit hash IDs.  They're *your names*.  They're keeping track of commits for you, according to your whims.  They're not my names—I can't touch *your* repository—so I can't affect your copies in your repository.

That's basically all there is to it.  Keep control over the parts you want control over.  Hand off control once you don't care any more.

Comment: Thank you. The last part is the important one: in other version control systems, I did not care too much for some branches. Because all changes were tracked with the employee's identity. If something went wrong without it getting noticed immediately, I could still always identify the person who made the mistake and undo it. This is not guaranteed in git. That's the part I could not really believe but that seems to be true anyways.

Comment: Note that an employee makes changes to the *employee's* Git repository. He (or other pronoun) can then submit changes, but unless you give him direct access to "the" (central, corporate) Git repo, he can't modify that one. If you gave him direct access to a Clearcase VOB or other storage media, he could wipe those too. What Git doesn't have, that many centralized systems do, is a whole authorization structure to go *with* their centralized control: they *must* provide this because there's only one copy of the repository. Git doesn't need to do that because there are so many copies.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that many people *want* it (they're still "thinking centralized", and you *can* be lazy and use Git in a centralized manner, giving everyone direct access, and then you do get this problem). But Git isn't a "solution" like those other systems, it's just a tool-set.